# multi-Figure with pgfplots with one legend and rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, rotating, legend

I would like to have in a page two figures like the one the code below at the same page using `subcaption` and `sidewaysfigure`. The first problem is that probably there is a mistake at the position of `sidewaysfigure` and the second one that it doesn't recognise the last three columns that I wanna include.

Moreover, given that I want just next to this to add another one (almost the same as this one; 1 for men and 1 for women), how can I have a single legend?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pst-tree,array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
    \usepackage{tkz-fct} \usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\author{Ioannis Galanakis}
\title{}
\date{}

\begin{filecontents*}{book.data
}
exper   y_fem_p y_fem_s y_fem_t y_fem_p_11  y_fem_s_11  y_fem_t_11
5               -.0786064   .0543229    .425381
6               -.0923139   .0650023    .5031813
7               -.10535 .07562  .5785562
8   -.0377879   .5229679    .8096244    -.1177149   .086176 .6515059
9   -.0408339   .5803306    .8990896    -.1294085   .0966702    .7220302
10  -.0435072   .6359136    .9859465    -.1404309   .1071028    .7901292
11  -.0458076   .6897169    1.0701950000000000  -.1507819   .1174736    .855803
12  -.0477353   .7417406    1.1518350000000000  -.1604617   .1277827    .9190514
13  -.0492902   .7919847    1.2308660000000000  -.1694702   .13803  .9798745
14  -.0504724   .8404492    1.307290000000000   -.1778074   .1482157    1.038272
15  -.0512817   .887134 1.3811040000000000  -.1854734   .1583396    1.094245
16  -.0517183   .9320391    1.4523110000000000  -.192468    .1684018    1.147792
17  -.0517821   .9751647    1.5209090000000000  -.1987914   .1784023    1.198914
18  -.0514732   1.016510000000000   1.5868980000000000  -.2044435   .1883411    1.24761
19  -.0507914   1.0560770000000000  1.6502790000000000  -.2094244   .1982181    1.293882
20  -.0497369   1.0938630000000000  1.7110520000000000  -.2137339   .2080334    1.337727
21  -.0483096   1.129870000000000   1.7692160000000000  -.2173722   .217787 1.379148
22  -.0465096   1.1640980000000000  1.8247720000000000  -.2203392   .2274789    1.418143
23  -.0443368   1.1965450000000000  1.87772000000000        -.2226349   .2371091    1.454713
24  -.0417912   1.2272140000000000  1.9280590000000000  -.2242594   .2466775    1.488858
25  -.0388728   1.2561020000000000  1.97579000000000        -.2252126   .2561843    1.520577
26  -.0355816   1.2832110000000000  2.0209120000000000  -.2254944   .2656292    1.549872
27  -.0319177   1.30854000000000        2.0634260000000000  -.225105    .2750125    1.57674
28  -.027881    1.3320890000000000  2.1033310000000000  -.2240444   .2843341    1.601184
29  -.0234715   1.3538590000000000  2.1406280000000000  -.2223124   .2935939    1.623202
30  -.0186893   1.373850000000000   2.1753170000000000  -.2199092   .302792 1.642795
31  -.0135343   1.392060000000000   2.2073970000000000  -.2168347   .3119284    1.659962
32  -.0080065   1.4084910000000000  2.2368690000000000  -.2130889   .3210031    1.674704
33  -.0021059   1.4231420000000000  2.2637320000000000  -.2086719   .330016 1.687021
34  .0041675    1.4360140000000000  2.2879870000000000  -.2035835   .3389673    1.696913
35  .0108136    1.4471060000000000  2.3096340000000000  -.1978239   .3478568    1.704379
36  .0178325    1.4564190000000000  2.3286720000000000  -.191393    .3566846    1.70942
37  .0252241    1.4639510000000000  2.3451020000000000  -.1842909   .3654507    1.712036
38  .0329886    1.4697040000000000  2.3589230000000000  -.1765174   .374155 1.712226
39  .0411258    1.4736780000000000  2.3701360000000000  -.1680727   .3827977    1.709991
40  .0496358    1.4758720000000000  2.3787410000000000  -.1589567   .3913786    1.705331
41  .0585185    1.4762860000000000  2.3847370000000000  -.1491694   .3998978    1.698245
42  .0677741    1.4749210000000000  2.3881240000000000  -.1387109   .4083552    1.688734
43  .0774024    1.4717760000000000  2.3889040000000000  -.127581    .416751 1.676798
44  .0874035    1.4668510000000000  2.3870750000000000  -.1157799   .425085 1.662437
45  .0977773    1.4601470000000000  2.3826370000000000  -.1033075   .4333573    1.64565
46  .108524 1.4516630000000000  2.3755910000000000  -.0901638   .4415679    1.626438
47  .1196434    1.4413990000000000  2.3659370000000000  -.0763489   .4497167    1.6048
48  .1311355    1.4293560000000000  2.3536740000000000  -.0618627   .4578039    1.580737
49  .1430005    1.4155330000000000  2.3388030000000000  -.0467052   .4658293    1.554249
50  .1552382    1.39993000000000        2.3213230000000000  -.0308764   .473793 1.525336
51  .1678487    1.3825480000000000  2.3012350000000000  -.0143763   .481695 1.493997
52  .180832 1.3633860000000000  2.2785390000000000  .002795 .4895353    1.460233
53  .1941881    1.3424450000000000  2.2532340000000000  .0206376    .4973138    1.424044
54  .2079169    1.3197240000000000  2.2253210000000000  .0391515    .5050306    1.385429
55  .2220185    1.2952230000000000  2.19480000000000        .0583367    .5126857    1.344389
56  .2364928    1.2689430000000000  2.16167000000000        .0781932    .5202791    1.300924
57  .25134  1.2408830000000000  2.1259310000000000  .0987209    .5278108    1.255034
58  .2665599    1.2110430000000000  2.0875840000000000  .1199199    .5352807    1.206718
59  .2821526    1.1794240000000000  2.0466290000000000  .1417902    .5426889    1.155977
60  .2981181    1.1460250000000000  2.0030660000000000  .1643317    .5500354    1.10281
61  .3144563    1.1108470000000000  1.9568940000000000  .1875446    .5573202    1.047218
62  .3311673    1.0738890000000000  1.9081130000000000  .2114287    .5645432    .9892012
63  .3482511    1.0351510000000000  1.8567240000000000  .2359841    .5717046    .9287588
64  .3657077    .9946333    1.8027270000000000  .2612107    .5788042    .8658911
65  .383537 .9523362    1.7461210000000000  .2871087    .5858421    .8005981
66  .4017392    .9082595    1.6869070000000000  .3136779    .5928183    .7328797
67  .420314 .8624031    1.6250850000000000  .3409185    .5997327    .6627361
68  .4392617    .8147671    1.5606540000000000  .3688302    .6065854    .5901671
69  .4585821    .7653515    1.4936140000000000  .3974133    .6133764    .5151728
70  .4782753    .7141563    1.4239670000000000  .4266676    .6201057    .4377532
71  .4983413    .6611813    1.3517110000000000  .4565932    .6267733    .3579083
72  .5187801    .6064268    1.2768460000000000  .4871902    .6333791    .2756381
73  .5395916    .5498927    1.1993730000000000          
74  .5607759    .4915788    1.1192920000000000          
75  .582333 .4314854    1.0366020000000000          

\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
width=0.7\textwidth,
       height=6cm,
    ymajorgrids,
xmajorgrids,
xlabel={$Experience$},
ylabel={$\ln[wage]$},
    title = {Profile},
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ytick scale label code/.code={v},
    legend pos=outer north east
      ]
        \addplot[mark=none, red,   ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_p] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Α'βάθμιας; 2008}
        \addplot[mark=none, brown,   ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_s] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Β' βάθμιας; 2008}
        \addplot[mark=none, blue,   ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_t] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Γ' βάθμιας; 2008}
  \addplot[mark=none, green,  ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_p_11] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Α'βάθμιας; 2011}
 \addplot[mark=none, orange,   ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_s_11] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Β' βάθμιας; 2011}
        \addplot[mark=none, purple,   ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_t_11] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Γ' βάθμιας; 2011}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please minimize your code and make it compilable. The third last line has to be `\end{sidewaysfigure}`. Why do you put that thing in a float if you do not use caption or label? Try to ask one specific question per post.

Comment: You are loading several packages twice. You should avoid that. About the column recognizance: Your first three rows are missing three values each. Put some zeros there and the error disappears.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{book.data}
    exper   y_fem_p y_fem_s y_fem_t y_fem_p_11  y_fem_s_11  y_fem_t_11
    5               -.0786064   .0543229    .425381 0 0 0 % added some values here
    6               -.0923139   .0650023    .5031813 0 0 0
    7               -.10535 .07562  .5785562 0 0 0
    8   -.0377879   .5229679    .8096244    -.1177149   .086176 .6515059
    9   -.0408339   .5803306    .8990896    -.1294085   .0966702    .7220302
    10  -.0435072   .6359136    .9859465    -.1404309   .1071028    .7901292
    11  -.0458076   .6897169    1.0701950000000000  -.1507819   .1174736    .855803
    12  -.0477353   .7417406    1.1518350000000000  -.1604617   .1277827    .9190514
    13  -.0492902   .7919847    1.2308660000000000  -.1694702   .13803  .9798745
    14  -.0504724   .8404492    1.307290000000000   -.1778074   .1482157    1.038272
    15  -.0512817   .887134 1.3811040000000000  -.1854734   .1583396    1.094245
    16  -.0517183   .9320391    1.4523110000000000  -.192468    .1684018    1.147792
    17  -.0517821   .9751647    1.5209090000000000  -.1987914   .1784023    1.198914
    18  -.0514732   1.016510000000000   1.5868980000000000  -.2044435   .1883411    1.24761
    19  -.0507914   1.0560770000000000  1.6502790000000000  -.2094244   .1982181    1.293882
    20  -.0497369   1.0938630000000000  1.7110520000000000  -.2137339   .2080334    1.337727
    21  -.0483096   1.129870000000000   1.7692160000000000  -.2173722   .217787 1.379148
    22  -.0465096   1.1640980000000000  1.8247720000000000  -.2203392   .2274789    1.418143
    23  -.0443368   1.1965450000000000  1.87772000000000        -.2226349   .2371091    1.454713
    24  -.0417912   1.2272140000000000  1.9280590000000000  -.2242594   .2466775    1.488858
    25  -.0388728   1.2561020000000000  1.97579000000000        -.2252126   .2561843    1.520577
    26  -.0355816   1.2832110000000000  2.0209120000000000  -.2254944   .2656292    1.549872
    27  -.0319177   1.30854000000000        2.0634260000000000  -.225105    .2750125    1.57674
    28  -.027881    1.3320890000000000  2.1033310000000000  -.2240444   .2843341    1.601184
    29  -.0234715   1.3538590000000000  2.1406280000000000  -.2223124   .2935939    1.623202
    30  -.0186893   1.373850000000000   2.1753170000000000  -.2199092   .302792 1.642795
    31  -.0135343   1.392060000000000   2.2073970000000000  -.2168347   .3119284    1.659962
    32  -.0080065   1.4084910000000000  2.2368690000000000  -.2130889   .3210031    1.674704
    33  -.0021059   1.4231420000000000  2.2637320000000000  -.2086719   .330016 1.687021
    34  .0041675    1.4360140000000000  2.2879870000000000  -.2035835   .3389673    1.696913
    35  .0108136    1.4471060000000000  2.3096340000000000  -.1978239   .3478568    1.704379
    36  .0178325    1.4564190000000000  2.3286720000000000  -.191393    .3566846    1.70942
    37  .0252241    1.4639510000000000  2.3451020000000000  -.1842909   .3654507    1.712036
    38  .0329886    1.4697040000000000  2.3589230000000000  -.1765174   .374155 1.712226
    39  .0411258    1.4736780000000000  2.3701360000000000  -.1680727   .3827977    1.709991
    40  .0496358    1.4758720000000000  2.3787410000000000  -.1589567   .3913786    1.705331
    41  .0585185    1.4762860000000000  2.3847370000000000  -.1491694   .3998978    1.698245
    42  .0677741    1.4749210000000000  2.3881240000000000  -.1387109   .4083552    1.688734
    43  .0774024    1.4717760000000000  2.3889040000000000  -.127581    .416751 1.676798
    44  .0874035    1.4668510000000000  2.3870750000000000  -.1157799   .425085 1.662437
    45  .0977773    1.4601470000000000  2.3826370000000000  -.1033075   .4333573    1.64565
    46  .108524 1.4516630000000000  2.3755910000000000  -.0901638   .4415679    1.626438
    47  .1196434    1.4413990000000000  2.3659370000000000  -.0763489   .4497167    1.6048
    48  .1311355    1.4293560000000000  2.3536740000000000  -.0618627   .4578039    1.580737
    49  .1430005    1.4155330000000000  2.3388030000000000  -.0467052   .4658293    1.554249
    50  .1552382    1.39993000000000        2.3213230000000000  -.0308764   .473793 1.525336
    51  .1678487    1.3825480000000000  2.3012350000000000  -.0143763   .481695 1.493997
    52  .180832 1.3633860000000000  2.2785390000000000  .002795 .4895353    1.460233
    53  .1941881    1.3424450000000000  2.2532340000000000  .0206376    .4973138    1.424044
    54  .2079169    1.3197240000000000  2.2253210000000000  .0391515    .5050306    1.385429
    55  .2220185    1.2952230000000000  2.19480000000000        .0583367    .5126857    1.344389
    56  .2364928    1.2689430000000000  2.16167000000000        .0781932    .5202791    1.300924
    57  .25134  1.2408830000000000  2.1259310000000000  .0987209    .5278108    1.255034
    58  .2665599    1.2110430000000000  2.0875840000000000  .1199199    .5352807    1.206718
    59  .2821526    1.1794240000000000  2.0466290000000000  .1417902    .5426889    1.155977
    60  .2981181    1.1460250000000000  2.0030660000000000  .1643317    .5500354    1.10281
    61  .3144563    1.1108470000000000  1.9568940000000000  .1875446    .5573202    1.047218
    62  .3311673    1.0738890000000000  1.9081130000000000  .2114287    .5645432    .9892012
    63  .3482511    1.0351510000000000  1.8567240000000000  .2359841    .5717046    .9287588
    64  .3657077    .9946333    1.8027270000000000  .2612107    .5788042    .8658911
    65  .383537 .9523362    1.7461210000000000  .2871087    .5858421    .8005981
    66  .4017392    .9082595    1.6869070000000000  .3136779    .5928183    .7328797
    67  .420314 .8624031    1.6250850000000000  .3409185    .5997327    .6627361
    68  .4392617    .8147671    1.5606540000000000  .3688302    .6065854    .5901671
    69  .4585821    .7653515    1.4936140000000000  .3974133    .6133764    .5151728
    70  .4782753    .7141563    1.4239670000000000  .4266676    .6201057    .4377532
    71  .4983413    .6611813    1.3517110000000000  .4565932    .6267733    .3579083
    72  .5187801    .6064268    1.2768460000000000  .4871902    .6333791    .2756381
    73  .5395916    .5498927    1.1993730000000000          
    74  .5607759    .4915788    1.1192920000000000          
    75  .582333 .4314854    1.0366020000000000  
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
%\begin{otherlanguage}{english} maybe you have to switch the language here
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[%
                ,group style={rows=2, vertical sep=2.5cm}
                ,width=0.7\textwidth
                ,height=6cm
                ,ymajorgrids
                ,xmajorgrids
                ,xlabel={Experience} % do not put text in $$
                ,ylabel={$\ln[\text{wage}]$}
                ,title = {Profile}
                ,x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}
                ,ytick scale label code/.code={v}
            ]
            \nextgroupplot[%
            ,legend to name=grouplegend
            ,mark=none
            ]
            \addplot[red,ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_p] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Α' βάθμιας; 2008} % added space here for better alignment
            \addplot[brown, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_s] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Β' βάθμιας; 2008}
            \addplot[blue, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_t] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Γ' βάθμιας; 2008}
            \addplot[green, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_p_11] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Α' βάθμιας; 2011}
            \addplot[orange, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_s_11] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Β' βάθμιας; 2011}
            \addplot[purple, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_t_11] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Γ' βάθμιας; 2011}
            \nextgroupplot[mark=none]
            \addplot[red, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_p] {book.data};
            \addplot[brown, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_s] {book.data};
            \addplot[blue, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_t] {book.data};
            \addplot[green, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_p_11] {book.data};
            \addplot[orange, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_s_11] {book.data};
            \addplot[purple, ultra thick] table[x=exper,y=y_fem_t_11] {book.data};
            \end{groupplot} 
            \node at (group c1r1.east) [anchor=west, yshift=-3.4cm, xshift=.6cm] {\ref{grouplegend}};       
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
%\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably would be better to rotate the legend as well, wouldn't it? I would guess `wage` is just that, wage/salary/money you get for a job, and as such should it should be `\text`/`\mathrm`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I have adapted both to your recommendations.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks so much. I'll take into account all your comments. One extra question how could we add a subcaption in this figure?