# Shared legend below a group of horizontally aligned figures in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, legend, examples, groupplots

> How should I run the following example code using `/pgfplots/legend to name={<name>}` to put a shared legend below a group of horizontally aligned figures?

The example code using `/pgfplots/legend to name={<name>}` in the `pgfplots` manual under "Legends outside of an axis" is as follows (the first two lines are added by myself).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{footnotesize,samples=10}
\begin{center}% note that \centering uses less vspace...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend columns=-1,
legend entries={$(x+0)^k$;,$(x+1)^k$;,$(x+2)^k$;,$(x+3)^k$},
legend to name=named,
title={$k=1$}]
\addplot {x};
\addplot {x+1};
\addplot {x+2};
\addplot {x+3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={$k=2$}]
\addplot {x^2};
\addplot {(x+1)^2};
\addplot {(x+2)^2};
\addplot {(x+3)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={$k=3$}]
\addplot {x^3};
\addplot {(x+1)^3};
\addplot {(x+2)^3};
\addplot {(x+3)^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\

\ref{named}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It ***should*** generate a shared legend *below* a group of three horizontally aligned figures:
[image: legend in the below]

However, it throws the error 
`Something is wrong -- perhaps a missing \item`, and generates a shared legend *to the right*.
[image: legend to the right]

The compiler blames the `begin{center} end{center}` environment. However, commenting them out does not help.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Do you really work in `standalone`?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi It *is* not compilable itself. The code is copied from the `pgfplots` manual. I have only added the first two lines `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}`.

Comment: At least surround it by `\begin{document}\end{document}`. I would do this with groupplots like I did here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248151 When you are in `standalone`, the `center` makes no sense.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Sorry, `\begin{document}\end{document}` added.  Thanks. I am using `standalone` because I want to generate a .pdf file and then import it into my main .tex file. I changed `standalone` to `article`, and it generated too much space around the figure.

Comment: Use `article`, and run `pdfcrop` on the PDF afterwards.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Following [the answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248151/23098) you mentioned, I have done it with `groupplots`. Thanks.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks. I have done it with `groupplots`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248151/23098) given by @LaRiFaRi, `groupplots` works for me ([code at ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5594e365a65e286932abbe80)):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{footnotesize,samples=10}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style = {group size = 3 by 1, horizontal sep = 50pt}, width = 6.0cm, height = 5.0cm]
        \nextgroupplot[ title = {$k=1$},
            legend style = { column sep = 10pt, legend columns = -1, legend to name = grouplegend,}]
            \addplot {x};   \addlegendentry{$(x+0)^k$}%
            \addplot {x+1}; \addlegendentry{$(x+1)^k$}
            \addplot {x+2}; \addlegendentry{$(x+2)^k$}
            \addplot {x+3}; \addlegendentry{$(x+3)^k$}
        \nextgroupplot[title = {$k=2$},]
            \addplot {x^2};
            \addplot {(x+1)^2};
            \addplot {(x+2)^2};
            \addplot {(x+3)^2};
        \nextgroupplot[title = {$k=3$},] 
            \addplot {x^3};
            \addplot {(x+1)^3};
            \addplot {(x+2)^3};
            \addplot {(x+3)^3};                    
    \end{groupplot}
    \node at ($(group c2r1) + (0,-4.0cm)$) {\ref{grouplegend}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```