# Latex: Two bar charts, the same legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have two bar charts side by side, and they share the same legend, I have tried to use `\addlegendentry{}`, but I find my self with a repeated legend!

[image: the output of the code]

Here is the code, what should I do (I tried two many solution online but nothing work):

```latex
\begin{figure*}[h!]
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.93\textwidth,height=0.4\textheight,compat=1.16}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   legend style={at={(0.5,-0.09)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic x coords={Precision,Recall,F1-Score,Accuracy},
    major tick length=0cm,
    xtick=data,
    ymin=75.0,
     enlarge x limits=0.2,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
    nodes near coords,
    ybar,
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
    bar width = 8pt,
]

\addplot
coordinates {(Precision,86.6) (Recall,86.0) (F1-Score,86.3) (Accuracy,98.4)};
\addlegendentry{KNN}

\addplot
coordinates {(Precision,87.6) (Recall,86.2) (F1-Score,86.5) (Accuracy,97.5)};
\addlegendentry{Neural Networks}

\addplot
coordinates {(Precision,85.9) (Recall,86.3) (F1-Score,86.1) (Accuracy,98.6)};
\addlegendentry{Decision Tree}

\addplot
coordinates {(Precision,87.1) (Recall,86.8) (F1-Score,87.0) (Accuracy,99.2)};
\addlegendentry{Random Forest}

\addplot
coordinates {(Precision,85.5) (Recall,82.8) (F1-Score,83.7) (Accuracy,97.4)};
\addlegendentry{SVM}

\addplot
coordinates {(Precision,77.9) (Recall,77.7) (F1-Score,75.9) (Accuracy,87.8)};
\addlegendentry{Naive Bayes}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}% NO EMPTY LINE HERE!!!!
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
   legend style={at={(0.5,-0.09)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic x coords={FPR,FNR},
    major tick length=0cm,
    xtick=data,
    ymin=0.0,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
    nodes near coords,
    ybar,
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
    bar width = 15pt,
]

\addlegendentry{KNN}
\addplot
coordinates {(FPR,7.90) (FNR,14.0)};

\addlegendentry{Neural Networks}
\addplot
coordinates {(FPR,3.45) (FNR,13.75)};

\addlegendentry{Decision Tree}
\addplot
coordinates {(FPR,0.39) (FNR,13.63)};

\addlegendentry{Random Forest}
\addplot
coordinates {(FPR,0.31) (FNR,13.13)};

\addlegendentry{SVM}
\addplot
coordinates {(FPR,5.38) (FNR,17.11)};

\addlegendentry{Naive Bayes}
\addplot
coordinates {(FPR,3.63) (FNR,22.19)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Left - No Interaction. Right - Interaction} \label{fig:M}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: You should have a look at this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326388/141947

Comment: Thank u sir for your comment, but i didn't understand the answer in this question  .. i'm newbie with Latex .. so i dont know what to do ..

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I guess the simplest way to achieve that would be to use `legend to name` in the `axis` options. Have a look for that in the [PGFPlots manual section 4.9.7 (v1.17)](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=267).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proposal using simplified code based on the `groupplots` library

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1},width=12cm,height=8cm]
        \nextgroupplot[
            %legend style={at={(mygroup.south)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={Precision,Recall,F1-Score,Accuracy},
            major tick length=0cm,
            xtick=data,
            ymin=75.0,
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
            nodes near coords,
            ybar,
            every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
            bar width = 8pt,
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,86.6) (Recall,86.0) (F1-Score,86.3) (Accuracy,98.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.6) (Recall,86.2) (F1-Score,86.5) (Accuracy,97.5)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.9) (Recall,86.3) (F1-Score,86.1) (Accuracy,98.6)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.1) (Recall,86.8) (F1-Score,87.0) (Accuracy,99.2)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.5) (Recall,82.8) (F1-Score,83.7) (Accuracy,97.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,77.9) (Recall,77.7) (F1-Score,75.9) (Accuracy,87.8)};
        %\legend{KNN,Neural Networks,Decision Tree,Random Forest,SVM,Naive Bayes}

        \nextgroupplot[
            legend style={at={(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/horizontal sep}/2,-0.1)},
                    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={FPR,FNR},
            major tick length=0cm,
            xtick=data,
            ymin=0.0,
            enlarge x limits=0.5,
            enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
            nodes near coords,
            ybar,
            every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
            bar width = 15pt,
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {(FPR,7.90) (FNR,14.0)};
        \addplot coordinates {(FPR,3.45) (FNR,13.75)};
        \addplot coordinates {(FPR,0.39) (FNR,13.63)};
        \addplot coordinates {(FPR,0.31) (FNR,13.13)};
        \addplot coordinates {(FPR,5.38) (FNR,17.11)};
        \addplot coordinates {(FPR,3.63) (FNR,22.19)};


        \legend{KNN,Neural Networks,Decision Tree,Random Forest,SVM,Naive Bayes}
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks u so much sir for answering me. i found an easy solution

```
\begin{figure*}[h!]
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.93\textwidth,height=0.4\textheight,compat=1.16}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[
    legend columns=-1,
    legend entries={KNN, Neural Networks, Decision Tree, Random  Forest, SVM, Naive Bayes},
    legend to name=named,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.09)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic x coords={Precision,Recall,F1-Score,Accuracy},
    major tick length=0cm,
    xtick=data,
    ymin=75.0,
     enlarge x limits=0.2,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
    nodes near coords,
    ybar,
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
    bar width = 8pt,
]

\addplot 
coordinates {(Precision,86.6) (Recall,86.0) (F1-Score,86.3) (Accuracy,98.4)};

\addplot        
coordinates {(Precision,87.6) (Recall,86.2) (F1-Score,86.5) (Accuracy,97.5)};

\addplot        
coordinates {(Precision,85.9) (Recall,86.3) (F1-Score,86.1) (Accuracy,98.6)};

\addplot        
coordinates {(Precision,87.1) (Recall,86.8) (F1-Score,87.0) (Accuracy,99.2)};

\addplot        
coordinates {(Precision,85.5) (Recall,82.8) (F1-Score,83.7) (Accuracy,97.4)};

\addplot        
coordinates {(Precision,77.9) (Recall,77.7) (F1-Score,75.9) (Accuracy,87.8)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}% NO EMPTY LINE HERE!!!! 
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}[
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.09)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic x coords={FPR,FNR},
    major tick length=0cm,
    xtick=data,
    ymin=0.0,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
    nodes near coords,
    ybar,
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
    bar width = 15pt,
]

\addplot 
coordinates {(FPR,7.90) (FNR,14.0)}; 

\addplot        
coordinates {(FPR,3.45) (FNR,13.75)};

\addplot 
coordinates {(FPR,0.39) (FNR,13.63)}; 

\addplot        
coordinates {(FPR,0.31) (FNR,13.13)};

\addplot 
coordinates {(FPR,5.38) (FNR,17.11)}; 

\addplot        
coordinates {(FPR,3.63) (FNR,22.19)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\ref{named}
\caption{Left - No Interaction. Right - Interaction}
\label{fig:M}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add an image of your result, so others have an easy way to see how your result looks like and can compare it to other answers.