# No colors in marks on pgfplots legend, using groupplots and standalone?

Tags: pgfplots, legend, tikzplotlib

I'm trying to make an image with 2 groupplots, and a single legend.
*Issue #1 should be evident: the legend is showing up to the right of the plots, not below them.* < This has been solved using a tabular environment and a single column.
The second issue is more subtle: the legend has no colors in the marks!

[image]

Here's a sort of template of my code, since it was generated by tikzplotlib (I'm using standalone to precompile the pdfs to then add into my main file):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\input{pre/fig-preamble}
\begin{document}
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.9.8.
\begin{tikzpicture}[
scale=1.0
]

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{1,0.498039215686275,0.0549019607843137}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.83921568627451,0.152941176470588,0.156862745098039}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1, horizontal sep=2cm}]
\nextgroupplot[
legend cell align={left},
legend columns=2,
legend style={
  fill opacity=0.8,
  draw opacity=1,
  text opacity=1,
  at={(0.97,0.03)},
  anchor=south east,
  draw=white!80!black
},
legend to name=namedleg1,
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
xlabel={Applied force in X [N]},
xmajorgrids,
xmin=-30, xmax=30,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
ylabel={Bridge Response [V/V]},
ymajorgrids,
ymin=-0.0015, ymax=0.0015,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\addplot [draw=color0, mark=triangle, only marks]
table{%
% DATAPOINTS
};
\addlegendentry{Bridge 0, Loading}
\end{groupplot}
```

*Here would be all other groupplots, datapoints, legend entries etc; I've removed them since it's just repetition*

```
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\ref{namedleg1}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve either (hopefully both) problems?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Solved - moved colors up a few lines, before the tabular env.

Comment: Ok, so issue #1 was solved with a tabular environment, which I somehow overlooked. Edited post to clarify

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547201/latex-two-bar-charts-the-same-legend.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.