# How to integrate three stacked bar charts in one figure?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a latex code for bar chart with a legend. I'm trying to add two more similar charts on the side to have 3 bar charts side by side with each chart having a sub-caption and the final figure should have a caption. Also, I want a same legend for all the three charts and need to add the labels for x and y axis.

Latex code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotsset{
        selective show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \ifnum\coordindex=#1
                   \node[
                   at={(normalized axis cs:%
                       \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                       \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                   },
                   anchor=south,
                   ]
                   {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
                \fi
            },
        },selective show sum on top/.default=0
    }

    \begin{axis}[width=8cm,
    ybar stacked, ymin=0,  
    bar width=8mm,
    symbolic x coords={3,6,12,24,48},
    xtick=data,
    yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},
    nodes near coords={\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=0}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize,  yshift=5.5pt},
    font=\footnotesize,
    legend style={at={(0.05,1.1)}, anchor=west, legend columns=2}, 
    ]

    \addplot [fill=black!20] coordinates {
        ({3},62)
        ({6},50)
        ({12},36)
        ({24},22)
        ({48},12)};
    \addplot [fill=olive!20] coordinates {
       ({3},34)
        ({6},46)
        ({12},61)
        ({24},76)
        ({48},87)};
    \addplot [fill=brown!80] coordinates {
        ({3},4)
        ({6},4)
        ({12},3)
        ({24},2)
        ({48},1)};
    \legend{Action Selection, Update all trainers, Other segments}
    \end{axis}
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My output:
[image]

Required output:
[image]

Comment: +1: If I were you, I would limit the question to one question and also provide a hand drawing of the desired output.

Comment: Hello, I just attached the desired output. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547201/  . It. seems that your question is duplicate to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups of plots can be created with the `groupplots` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotsset{
        selective show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \ifnum\coordindex=#1
                   \node[
                   at={(normalized axis cs:%
                       \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                       \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                   },
                   anchor=south,
                   ]
                   {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
                \fi
            },
        },selective show sum on top/.default=0
    }

    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 1},
        /pgfplots/legend style={at={(-0.75,1.1)}, anchor=south, legend columns=3}]
        \pgfplotsset{my bar/.style={width=6cm,
            ybar stacked, ymin=0,  
            bar width=3mm,
            symbolic x coords={3,6,12,24,48},
            xtick=data,
            yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},
            nodes near coords={\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=0}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
            nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize,  yshift=5.5pt},
            font=\footnotesize,
            }}
        \nextgroupplot[my bar]
            \addplot [fill=black!20] coordinates {
                ({3},62)
                ({6},50)
                ({12},36)
                ({24},22)
                ({48},12)};
            \addplot [fill=olive!20] coordinates {
                ({3},34)
                ({6},46)
                ({12},61)
                ({24},76)
                ({48},87)};
            \addplot [fill=brown!80] coordinates {
                ({3},4)
                ({6},4)
                ({12},3)
                ({24},2)
                ({48},1)};
                \nextgroupplot[my bar]
                \addplot [fill=black!20] coordinates {
                    ({3},62)
                    ({6},50)
                    ({12},36)
                    ({24},22)
                    ({48},12)};
                \addplot [fill=olive!20] coordinates {
                    ({3},34)
                    ({6},46)
                    ({12},61)
                    ({24},76)
                    ({48},87)};
                \addplot [fill=brown!80] coordinates {
                    ({3},4)
                    ({6},4)
                    ({12},3)
                    ({24},2)
                    ({48},1)};
                \nextgroupplot[my bar]
                    \addplot [fill=black!20] coordinates {
                        ({3},62)
                        ({6},50)
                        ({12},36)
                        ({24},22)
                        ({48},12)};
                    \addplot [fill=olive!20] coordinates {
                        ({3},34)
                        ({6},46)
                        ({12},61)
                        ({24},76)
                        ({48},87)};
                    \addplot [fill=brown!80] coordinates {
                        ({3},4)
                        ({6},4)
                        ({12},3)
                        ({24},2)
                        ({48},1)};                    
    \legend{Action Selection, Update all trainers, Other segments}
    \end{groupplot}
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]